# CSS border style inside

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

[image: Boder]

I want to create a border as shown in the image. I tried with all the styles inset, outset,ridge and groove but I was not able to get the expected result.
Is there any way to bend border towards inside till middle and get back towards till top(hope you understand the problem).

If it's repeated question please add the solution link.

Thanks in advance.
I have tried this:

```
        div {  
              border-bottom: 1px ridge #B5B9BB;
              /*border-bottom: 1px inset #B5B9BB;
              border-bottom: 1px outset #B5B9BB;
              border-bottom: 1px groove #B5B9BB; */
            }
```

Comment: Show us what you tried?? Show us code.

Comment: it will be great if you could add the code here. http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Can you try to explain it better? Maybe take a screenshot of what you have and what you want.

Comment: What you want is not exactly clear. Please provide some code.

Comment: your border needs to be at least 2 pixels to show 2 colors. groove seems fine http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zxeOGV

Comment: @GCyrillus's code is the best. if you need double border with two different color of your choice then use one as border and other as shadow.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `outline`:

```css
.bordered {
    border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
    background: aliceblue;
    outline: 5px solid aliceblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="bordered">Available Apps</div>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/s2xwzuqx/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Seems why not just use a border on the text?

```css
div {
  background: lightgrey;
  padding: 0.5em;
}
p {
  border-bottom: 1px ridge #B5B9BB;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Available Apps</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is probably best to use a wrapping element if possible; it is more flexible than `outline` (supports border-radius, box-shadows etc.)

For example:

```
<div class="headline-area">
    <h2>Available Apps</h2>
</div>
```

with the CSS:

```
.headline-area {
  background:#D4D9DC;
  padding:5px;
}  
.headline-area h2 {
  border-bottom:1px solid #B5B9BB;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I am in your situation I use `box-shadow`:

```css
body {
    background:#D1D6D9;
    font-family:verdana;
}
div {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #B5B9BB;
    box-shadow:0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,.7);
    padding-bottom:5px;
}
```

```html
<div>Available Apps</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could always try a hr tag. You can then style it in CSS to your desired preference.

HTML

```
New apps 
<hr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Also but you need an extra Div to do so.

***HTML***

```
<div class="outerDiv">
    COntent
    <div class="innerDiV">
    </div>
<div>
```

***CSS***

```
.outerDiv{
    background-color: grey;
  height: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 25px;
}
.innerDiV{
   margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 98%;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bc52k0hj/4/)